# why cant i find the parameter i use in analytics on data source?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a nice dashboard view with charts i wanted in google analytics. some of them are "sessions by traffic sources" and "sessions by device category".

All i want is to bring these charts into one page in google data studio, but i cant find anything about sessions or traffic sources under dimensions or metrics.They use the same database so why cant i find the same data in both software?

I get so many "Available fields" but they're all irrelevant to what I want to display

Comment: Are you sure you are setting up your data source correctly? I am confused, because I can see this stuff fine in GDS.

Comment: @MandyShaw yea when i click "connect to google analytics" i get all these options but most of them are useless fr me. are these generated or someone made them? https://i.imgur.com/u2rVZqq.png

Comment: Do me a screenshot of your dashboard view showing the information you're looking for, include it in the question, and I'll try and explain where the relevant stuff is in GDS.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to edit your fields at too basic a level. The list of fields you're seeing when you add Google Analytics as a data source is **ALL** GA dimensions and metrics. Just click to add it as a data source, you do not want to try editing or choosing your dimensions and metrics at this point. Once you've connected the data source, you have all GA dimensions and metrics available to you, and you can just pick out what you want each table or chart to use from them.